# jQuery Selector with value not fetching due to some characters in a string of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a group of checkboxes containing values from 1 to 5 then Other with textbox such as:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="CheckGroup" id="chk_1" value="1" />fortunate
<input type="checkbox" class="CheckGroup" id="chk_2" value="2" />Surprise
<input type="checkbox" class="CheckGroup" id="chk_3" value="3" />Whatever
<input type="checkbox" class="CheckGroup" id="chk_4" value="4" />OutofWords
<input type="checkbox" class="CheckGroup" id="chk_5" value="5" />Nevermind
<input type="checkbox" class="CheckGroup CheckGroupOther" id="chk_Other" value="Other" />Other<br>
<input type='text' id="txtOther" class="form-control" style="display: none;" require="please enter a value" />
```

The user checked the "Other" and saved this value `"TESTINGfor123444((*&&^<>>??""::"`

now when the page loads i have this algorithm that sets the value which works fine when string value doesn't have this part "<>>"

```
var indiArr = data.Indications.split('||');
        if (indiArr != "") {
            for (var i = 0; i < indiArr.length; i++) {
                var chk = $('input.CheckGroup[value="' + indiArr[i] + '"]');
                if (chk.length > 0) {
                    chk.prop('checked', true);
                }
                else if (!isnum(indiArr[i])) {
                    $('input.CheckGroupOther').prop('checked', true);
                    $('[id$=txtOther]').removeAttr('style').attr('validate', 'AddOrderAdditionalGroup').val(indiArr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now Since  the string value is this `"TESTINGfor123444((*&&^<>>??""::"`
this selector `$('input.IndicationCheckGroup[value="' + indiArr[i] + '"]');`
returns 'Text' object, when it should return nothing because there is no checkbox with this value exists and set "Other" as defined in algorithm.

i have also tried the alternatives that are:

1. `indiArr[i].toString()`
2. `JSON.stringify(indiArr[i])`
3. `"TESTINGfor123444((*&&^<>>??\"\"::"`  - added back slash to escape double quotes and also tried the back slash on the characters that are causing this issue.

but none of the above helped.
I have also investigated all string's characters throughly and the part where it started returning `text`object was after adding this part "`<>>`" also tested skipping it which made the string to work as normal.

for now i have handled it using `if (chk.length > 0 && chk.is(':checkbox'))` which i don't think will is proper and general, its specific to this scenario.
But Is there a general and proper way to handle this sort of issue which covers all the scenarios? thanks

Comment: I did not downvote, but there are more reasons for downvoting than not knowing an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: @Yunnosch i respect your comment and i have read the link and tell me what information have i not provided which wouldn't help the reader? i feel that my question is directly stating the problem instead of the whole essay writing?

Comment: i have handled this problem that occurred, but i am willing to know a solution which would be general and would cover all the scenarios.

Comment: Sorry, your actual question is outside of my expertise. That is why I do not vote or answer (exactly as you said ;-). I just wanted to help you with understanding the voting concept. I feel with you for the frustration caused by downvotes and thought more info might sooth it.

Comment: well, thanks bro @Yunnosch  :)

Comment: By the way, I do not see anything wrong with your question, but that might be my lack of knowledge on the technologies. I hereby encourage downvoters to explain their voting. But please understand that it is a very important part of the voting, that it is completly acceptable to do it anonymously.

Comment: if you have handled the problem then this OP does not belong in this site it belongs to another site,check code review.. not my downvote FYI

Comment: @guradio Interesting. But I think asking for a cleaner solution after applying a non-portable/non-generic patch is still an acceptable question here.

Comment: Maybe you should collect available values from checkboxes, get array like `[1,2,3,4,5]` and check if current element exists in this array. If no - it's the `other` checkbox.

Comment: Just to clarify (after reading my first comment again): Downvoting because of just not knowing an answer is of course a **bad** reason for downvoting. But, sadly, it probably **is** one of the reasons out there...

Comment: Or maybe prefix `other` value with some prefix when save. On show you check if current element has this prefix and output accordingly.

Comment: @u_mulder that would work too. However, wouldn't it be great if  it is handled from client end i.e. javaScript which would be helpful for many and generic regardless of how you are storing the data. We all will learn something here about javascript with this solution that is what i seek and the reason why i asked the question, thanks though. :)

Comment: Offtopic: you seem to have some major problems validating user input.  The problem as described is that you're creating a jquery selector based on user input.  But there are problems higher up - in that your converting user input to an array by splitting on `,` - so if user enters `','"` you'll have all sorts of other problems.  End result: don't use user input in your code.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the suggestion, i have replaced it with the PIPE "||"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while i was waiting for an answer here i was also on a lookout for the generic solution to get rid of the object type specification such as: `chk.is(':checkbox')` or `chk.is(':radio')`

After quiet much of search what i could find best to remove the object type check and keep it generic is by adding the regex to check the special characters `((*&&^<>>??""::` from `TESTINGfor123444((*&&^<>>??""::`

**Declared and instantiated regex exp at the scope of loading and setting data function:**

```
var rgx = new RegExp(/[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]/g); //indentifies all the special characters
```

used it for all the checkbox/radio groups that had **Text field** appearance/disappearance and validation dependent **Other Radio/checkbox** click

```
function SetField(dataArr, parentSelector, groupClassName) {
    if (dataArr != "") {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
            var field = $(parentSelector).find('input.' + groupClassName + '[value="' + dataArr[i] + '"]');
            if (!rgx.test(dataArr[i])) {
                if (field.length > 0) {
                    field.prop('checked', true);
                }
                else {
                    $(parentSelector).find('input[value=Other]').not('input[type=text]').prop('checked', true);
                    $(parentSelector).find('input[type=text]').removeAttr('style').attr('validate', 'AddOrderAdditionalGroup').val(dataArr[i]);
                }
            }
            else {
                $(parentSelector).find('input[value=Other]').not('input[type=text]').prop('checked', true);
                $(parentSelector).find('input[type=text]').removeAttr('style').attr('validate', 'AddOrderAdditionalGroup').val(dataArr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as per above function, a little change in html was added which is the parent `div/fieldset` to have a class for inputs inside it.

```
<fieldset class="responseGroup">
<input type="checkbox" class="ResponseCheckGroup" id="chk_1" value="1" />fortunate
<input type="checkbox" class="ResponseCheckGroup" id="chk_2" value="2" />Surprise
<input type="checkbox" class="ResponseCheckGroup" id="chk_3" value="3" />Whatever
<input type="checkbox" class="ResponseCheckGroup" id="chk_4" value="4" />OutofWords
<input type="checkbox" class="ResponseCheckGroup" id="chk_5" value="5" />Nevermind
<input type="checkbox" class="ResponseCheckGroup ResponseCheckGroupOther" id="chk_Other" value="Other" />Other<br>
<input type='text' id="txtOther" class="form-control" style="display: none;" require="please enter a value" />
</fieldset>
```

and finally calling the function like this:

```
SetField(["1","4","5","TESTINGfor123444((*&&^<>>??\"\"::"],'.responseGroup','ResponseCheckGroup')
```

However if you happen to have special characters in your check/radio group's value then you can remove those from the regex for them to be included in the check.

but if this function can become even more better, please suggest/edit/update the answer. I'll greatly appreciate it, thanks! :)

**EDITED** as per the different scenarios i faced until now:

```
function SetField(data, parentSelector, groupClassName) {
    if (data != null) {
        if (typeof data === "object") {
            if (data != "") {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var field = $(parentSelector).find('input.' + groupClassName + '[value="' + data[i] + '"]');
                    if (!rgx.test(data[i])) {
                        if (field.length > 0) {
                            field.prop('checked', true);
                        }
                        else {
                            $(parentSelector).find('input[value=Other]').not('input[type=text]').prop('checked', true);
                            $(parentSelector).find('input[type=text]').removeAttr('style').attr('validate', 'AddOrderAdditionalGroup').val(data[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $(parentSelector).find('input[value=Other]').not('input[type=text]').prop('checked', true);
                        $(parentSelector).find('input[type=text]').removeAttr('style').attr('validate', 'AddOrderAdditionalGroup').val(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (typeof data === "boolean") {
            var field = $('input.' + groupClassName + '[value="' + data + '"]');
            if (field.length > 0) {
                field.prop('checked', true);
            }
        }
        else if (typeof data === "string") {
            if (data === "true" || data === "false") {
                var field = $('input.' + groupClassName + '[value="' + data + '"]');
                if (field.length > 0) {
                    field.prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```